# Magento 2 - Trying to get the items from the order into the success page

Tags: magento2.2.6

I am trying to pull the products from the order on the success page, but it keeps returning with "0" when I do var_dump.

```
<?php
namespace CJ\CJTracking\Block\Checkout;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{

    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_currency;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $orderId;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $lastOrder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_currency = $currency;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $checkoutSession, $orderConfig, $httpContext, $data);
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $lastOrder = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $this->orderId = $lastOrder->getIncrementId();
        $this->lastOrder = $lastOrder->getData();
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getOrderId()
    {
        return $this->orderId;
    }

    public function getAllVisibleitems()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
        return $order->getAllVisibleitems();
    }

    public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }

    public function getGrandTotal()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
        return $order->getGrandTotal();
    }

    public function getSubtotal()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
        return $order->getSubtotal();
    }

    public function getDiscountAmount()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
        return $order->getDiscountAmount();
    }
    public function getCouponCode()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
        return $order->getCouponCode();
    }

}
```

and the phtml is:

```
<?php
$cjevent = "";

$cjevent = isset($_COOKIE["cjevent"]) ? $_COOKIE["cjevent"] : '';

$order = $block->getOrderId();
$items = $block->getAllVisibleitems();
var_dump($items);
$itemstrings = "";
$itemcount = 0;
$discount = $block->getDiscountAmount();
$coupon = $block->getCouponCode();
$currency = $block->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
echo "#currency: ".$currency;
$amount = $block->getSubtotal();
$customer_email = $block->getCustomerEmail();

/** avoiding double ITEM parameters for the same sku */
$last_checked = "";
/** if order count > 1 we need item based parameter strings */
if(count($items)  > 0){
foreach($items as $item){

    if($item->getSku() != $last_checked){
        $itemcount++;
    $last_checked = $item->getSku();
    $stripped_sku = str_replace('#','',$last_checked);
    $itemcount_float = floatval($item->getQtyOrdered());
    $rounded_count = round($itemcount_float,0);
    $rounded_amount = round($item->getPrice(),2);
    $itemstrings .= "&ITEM".$itemcount."=".$stripped_sku."&AMT".$itemcount."=".$rounded_amount."&QTY".$itemcount
    ."=".$rounded_count."&DCNT".$itemcount."=".$item->getBaseDiscountAmount();
    }
}}

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $utype = "407887";
    } else {
        $utype = "407886";
    }

?>

<img class="d-none" src="https://www.emjcd.com/u?TYPE=<?= $utype; ?>&CID=1550236<?= $itemstrings; ?>&COUPON=<?= $coupon; ?>&OID=<?= $order; ?>&CURRENCY=&CJEVENT=<?= $cjevent; ?>&METHOD=IMG">
```

**UPDATED**

I just replaced getItemsCollection with getAllVisibleitems, but still, I cannot access the order data for some reason!

Comment: Check the sizeof items collecction by sizeof($items), if its greater than 0 then try to print $item->getData() in foreach loop.

Comment: When I did this, it did pull the order data properly, but still, I got an error when I tried to $item->getSku();

Answer (score 0):

In success block, please update getItemsCollection() with below code:

```
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    ...
}

public function getItemsCollection()
{
    $orderId = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getLastOrderId();
    $order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

    return $orderItems; 
}
```

Check and let me know how it goes.. I didn't check it at my end.

**Updates:**

Update my code, please check by adding new dependency of object manager and clearing cache and generation files.

Comment: Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid method Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Interceptor::create(Array
(
)
)

Comment: Try updated answer.. don't forget to remove generation files (generated/code) after updates.

Comment: I do not think is the proper way to have this done, like the items already returning with the proper data, but it stops when I do try to get the sku from $items->getData();

Answer (score 0):

In below line you getting Order Increment Id

```
$this->orderId = $lastOrder->getIncrementId();
```

but when you load your order object , you are trying with Order entity id as place of increment id
so try to change below line

```
$order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
```

with below line with order increment id

```
$order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->orderId);
```

in getAllVisibleitems method.